# Woes with the selected button state in custom UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with two buttons in it, mycell.m/mycell.h/mycell.xib. In the XIB I have given the buttons a sample label, and I change that text in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`.

Now, when I click the buttons, while I'm holding my finger on it, it will show the sample text instead of the actual text. And should I miss the button and touch inside the custom UITableViewCell, both buttons change text to the sample text, and they don't redisplay the text I set in cellForRowAtIndexPath until I scroll the cell off-screen and back again.

Any clues to what I might be doing wrong? I haven't found any way to set a selected text.

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, trying again...

I set up a mini project and recreated the problem.  After puzzling over why the text I set wasn't being used, I finally realized that you can set a different title for every control state (setTitle:forState:). Normally, if you just set titleLabel.text, then you're setting it for UIControlStateNormal, which is then used by default for all other states.  However, IB apparently sets the sample title you specify for all the states separately, not just for normal state. So in your code, you're indirectly doing a setTitle:forState:UIControlStateNormal, but the titles set by IB for all the other states are remaining unchanged.  So when you hold down the button (UIControlStateSelect) or you hit the cell (UIControlStateHighlight), then the sample label is displayed.  SO...either remove the sample label in IBuilder (the easy path), OR set the label for all the relevant states.

Old incorrect answer:

cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called when the tableView needs to display a cell (e.g. when scrolling back onto the screen.) It's not called anytime a cell is on the screen. Sounds like you've got another routine (e.g. buttonPressed) that's set up as an IBAction from the buttons.

Comment: This is true, you can call [self.tableView reloadData] on the button press to make the cells refresh.

Comment: Correct, I've got a routine hooked up to the buttons, but that seems to fire nicely. It's just while pressing the button or touching in the cell outside the button area that the text reverts to the sample-text. Even setting the button text in didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't set the text right, but calling [tableView reloadData] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath actually does work, but it seems like the wrong solution

Comment: Thank you sooo much for working through it and discovering what I could not. I hadn't given setTitle:forState: a thought, since, as you said, I was working with the label's text-property instead. Thank you soo much! :-) Hope to be buying you some beers some time :-)